# Действительно ли по новым правилам слово "кофе" среднего рода?

Tags: существительные, род

Многие говорят, что согласно новым правилам "кофе" официально стал(о) считаться существительным среднего рода. Насколько это соответствует действительности?

Если это действительно так, то когда было принято это правило, и считается ли ошибкой использование "кофе" как существительного мужского рода?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

С 1 сентября 2009 года вошел в силу приказ министерства образования и науки России от 8 июня 2009, определяющий список словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка.

В этот список вошел "Грамматический словарь русского языка" под редакцией Андрея Зализняка.  Согласно этому изданию, "кофе" теперь может быть среднего рода.

Comment: Супер, то, что я искал! Спасибо

Comment: Russian-speaking users of RLU.SE may find this article interesting: http://gtmarket.ru/news/state/2009/09/01/2146 I am sorry, it's too long to translate it into English, but basically this new list of dictionaries has caused many questions. It doesn't include most respected references and all dictionaries in the list are published by the same publishing house.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, the former form of кофе was кофий. The latter is clearly masculine.

кофе ends in an "e." Most Russian words that end in this letter are neuter.

That would lead some to treat the word кофе as neuter. Is this fully accepted at this time? No, it still retains its masculine gender in the eyes of many people--for now. But the language is evolving, with the underlying word having taken the -e form, so acceptance of the neuter gender has become more and more so over time, and will probably continue to grow.

Answer (score 4):

No, it hasn't. It is a colloquial form. See here: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EA%EE%F4%E5&all=x

**Update** (as of 2012-06-15):

> (Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук. Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин. 2007)
>
> кофе, нескл., м. и (разг.) с.
>
> (Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов. 2009)
>
> КОФЕ, неизм.; м.
>
> (Русское словесное ударение.Словарь нарицательных имён. Автор М. В. Зарва. 2001)
>
> кофе [не фэ], нескл., м.

Another reference, to answer exactly the OP question: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/hot10/

> Q: Is it true that кофе is now neuter?
>
> A: It is true that кофе can be used in spoken language as neuter noun. It is untrue that is is "now". This norm was mentioned already in 1970-80s. According to the strict norm it is still masculine.

Comment: texnic, can you add more content in your answer? It's ok to link, but if you don't write the most relevant part here, the answer loses quality.

Comment: Well, it's the dictionaries that reflect the official language in Russian. So until they are updated, it is not officially enforced.

Comment: @texnic, you are wrong, it is officially accepted and recognised form, this has nothing to do with current state of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

Справочная служба русского языка, [#257524](http://pda.gramota.ru/?page=93&action=buro&s=257524):

> Что касается слово кофе: указание на допустимость его употребления в разговорной речи как существительного среднего рода находим еще в словарях 1970-80-х гг. (см., например, Скворцов Л. И. Правильно ли мы говорим по-русски? М.: Знание, 1980). Поэтому говорить о том, что слово кофе теперь и среднего рода, некорректно.