# Has заец really become an acceptable spelling?

Tags: лексикон, орфография, правописание

This is a follow up to the question [Has кофе become neutral?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/128/has-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5-officially-become-neutral)

I have read somewhere on the web that it is now acceptable to write `заец` instead of `заяц`.  Not that I am going to do that, just like I am going to continue to use `кофе` as masculine.  Just curious.

Comment: Shouting `Заеееец` in the wild is still a good way to summon an avalanche.

Comment: Note that the louder you shout `Ну, заец!`, the safer you are. Thats an inexplicable paradox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I remember reading a while ago (so I tracked it down) an article from Известия on this subject: http://www.izvestia.ru/news/250227

As far as I understand/remember/know, this was one of the possible suggested spelling changes, however it did not even make it into any official drafts.  So, AFAIK, this is wrong.  And hare is still spelled as заяц.

Comment: Good! The order in the Universe has been restored. :)

Answer (score 12):

There is [not a single dictionary](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E7%E0%E5%F6) that lists "заец".

You mentioned the case of кофе as an analogy. Well, I should argue that it's not, really. All the words in Russian that end in е are neutral, except for coffee. So, logically, it should be neutral as well, it's just that we have traditionally used it as masculine and its usage as neutral hits the ear wrong with no linguistic or logical reason whatsoever, only historical reasons.

The spelling заец, on the other hand, is completely illogical. Consider the plural - зайцы. The я->й shift is common in Russian, however, е->й is not. So, there would be no compelling reason to accept this weird spelling.

Comment: I am guessing that `кофе` started out as `кофий`, which explains why it is masculine. That also makes it consistent with `чай`. ;)

Comment: `Кофе` is not all the words, because it was borrowed.

Comment: Actually, `заяц` is the only surviving Russian word with a fleeting `я` (historically, fleeting `ѩ`, a nasal vowel). Fleeting `е`, on the other hand, is quite common: *кореец*, *нанаец*, *молотобоец*.

Comment: As far as I remember the spelling of this word had to be changed in 1918 along with other similar words, but the authors of the reform decided that new spelling will look weird in this particular case.

Comment: _All the words in Russian that end in е are neutral_ 
 - you probably only mean inanimate words. Otherwise they can very well be masculine: _падре, подмастерье, шансонье_.

Comment: As Quassnoi said, it is the only case of fleeting vowel surfacing as "я" in written Russian. So, for example, Zaliznyak has to add a special rule to convert his morphophonological "заj*ц" to "заяц" not to "заец".

Answer (score 3):

Note that outside of the animal world, `Заец` is a perfectly valid and relatively common family name...

Comment: Note that it comes from Ukrainian `заєць`.