# Кофий и кофе - что от чего произошло? Is the кофе derived from кофий or vice versa?

Tags: этимология

Артемий Лебедев в своем "ководстве" [пишет](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/138/):

> Мужской род бедному напитку достался от устаревших форм «кофий» или «кофей».

У Корнея Чуковского в книге "Живой как жизнь" [сказано](http://book-online.com.ua/read.php?book=1581&page=7):

> Русский язык вообще тяготеет к склонению несклоняемых слов. Не потому ли, например, создалось слово кофий, что кофе никак не возможно склонять?

Так все же - какая форма слова "кофе" от какой произошла? Они заимствованы независимо или "кофий" - это просторечное слово от "кофе"? Или сначала был все-таки "кофий"?

(Чуковский для меня более авторитетный автор, но и у него встречаются устаревшие сведения о происхождении слов).

---

I have read in different sources that

- "кофе" is masculine because it was used as "кофий" in the past and the latter word has masculine ending.
- "кофе" is indeclinable and that's why the word "кофий" emerged.

So, which word was the first to be borrowed? And which word was the initial one?

Comment: А кто сказал, что "кофе" мужского рода? Мне всегда казалось что "Один кофе пожалуйста" звучит очень высокопарно. Намного благозвучнее "Одно кофе, пожалуйста." И это зафиксировано в словаре: [Викисловарь/кофе](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0) Правда пока только как "допустимо" но так как языки меняются, то в следующей редакцией, наверное мужско

Comment: @johnfound Этот вопрос обсуждался здесь: [Действительно ли по новым правилам слово “кофе” среднего рода?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/128/551)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surprisingly, both forms have been introduced relatively at the same time.
This happens quite often with foreign words - different form coexist (especially in colloquial speech) for a quite a long time, till one of the forms is recognized de-facto as the only accepted one.

Here's [a quote](http://ec-dejavu.ru/c-2/Coffee.html):

> Слово «кофе» фиксируется в русском языке с середины XVII века 29. В
>   годы петровского правления словоформа «кофе» варьируется («кофий»,
>   «кофей», «кохей», «кефа», «кофа», «кофь», «кафе») в возможном
>   соответствии с аналогиями в западноевропейских и восточных языках
>   (голландский koffie, арабский gahwa, немецкий Kaffee, итальянский
>   cafe, польский kawa, турецкий kahve).

See, there's no such thing as a strict and well-established procedure for introducing new loanwords into the language. This is how it actually happens. Some merchants started to export coffee to Russia. Some of them keep business relations with, say, Netherlands. Some of them keep tights with, well, whatever, some other countries and regions. Those merchants - and first consumers of goods they sell - were early adopters of such new terminology.

Comment: It is interesting that according to [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=кофий%2Cкофей%2Cкефа%2Cкафе%2Cкофа%2Cкофе%2Cкофь&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=12&smoothing=3&share=) кофе was always the dominant written form of 7 alternatives since 1750. There is only one small 5-year period between 1785 and 1790 where "ко́фей" wins (other forms are almost invisible in the chart). It is also interesting that both ко́фей and ко́фе in fast speech are pronounced almost exactly. So I think Lebedev's claim on masculine influence of ко́фей is not correct at all.

Comment: @Artemix Ну, если вы будете писать слово «кофій» через восьмиричное «и», то конечно ничего не найдете. Впрочем, и правильно написав, ничего не найдете, ибо корпус Гугля отказывается верить, что в русском тексте может встречаться буква «і».

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Детализация результатов поиска показывает что гугл включает "кофій" в результаты поиска "кофий".