# Why some masculine nouns are usually tretead as neuter?

Tags: грамматика

Why some masculine nouns, like **кофе**, are treated as neuter?

Comment: You say "some". Do you know any other example except "кофе"?

Comment: @Abakan Actually no, but I used "some" just in case there are more.

Comment: But you are right, there are more: **авто** and **метро** were once masculine because they were shortened versions of **автомобиль** and **метрополитен**. Both are neuter nowadays.

Comment: @  Sergey Slepov --метро is not masculine), nor is авто) The only other masculine word is домишко.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just your post is strangely worded. It would be better to say "there were more..."

Comment: @Trey use some when you mean some, your question is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кофе is a loanword and a special case. It is grammatically masculine, but it ends in -е, which is consistent with the neuter gender in Russian. So, many native speakers incorrectly use it as though it is neuter.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear why the word that looks like a neuter noun and initially in 1700s was used as a neuter noun, later became a masculine noun.

For a long time grammar rules required "кофе" to be treated as a masculine noun. 
 Recently, in 2009, [grammar rules were officially relaxed](https://www.pravda.ru/society/01-09-2009/322376-slovar-0/) (the link is in Russian).  You can either treat it as a masculine, or as a neuter noun. Now phrases *"черное кофе" / black coffee* and *"горячее кофе" / hot coffee* are considered to be grammatically correct.

Comment: It's at least disputable that "кофе" derives from "кофий". See answers to [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2686)

Comment: What grammar rules were relaxed exactly? Кофе being neuter is actually more in line with the existing rule "Nouns ending in **-е** are usually neuter".

Comment: @Sergey Slepov Prior to 2009, using "кофе" as a neuter noun was considered a mistake. Back in my elementary school days a teacher would give me a lower grade for such a mistake.

Comment: @Abakan Yes, the evidence is non existent. Ruscorpora contains examples that at first, in 1700s,  "кофе" was used as a neuter noun, but by the late 1700s it became a masculine noun. It is unclear what caused that change. I updated the answer.